# sort data.frame based on the number of identical repeats in a column

Tags: r

I want to sort the data.frame based on the highest number of times a given character is repeated in the last column

data=

```
 chr    start   end name
    1   234   267   ttn
    2   345   367   Elm
    3   445   489   ttn
    4   544   598   Rm
    5   644   680   ttn
```

i want some thing like this

```
 chr    start   end name
    1   234 267 ttn
    3   445 489 ttn
    5   644 680 ttn
    2   345 367 Elm
    4   544 598 Rm
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a quick `data.table` approach which will sort the data by reference

```
library(data.table)
setorder(setDT(df)[, indx := .N, by = name], -indx)[]
#    chr start end name indx
# 1:   1   234 267  ttn    3
# 2:   3   445 489  ttn    3
# 3:   5   644 680  ttn    3
# 4:   2   345 367  Elm    1
# 5:   4   544 598   Rm    1
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
 data[with(data, order(-ave(seq_along(name), name, FUN=length))),]
 #    chr start end name
 #1   1   234 267  ttn
 #3   3   445 489  ttn
 #5   5   644 680  ttn
 #2   2   345 367  Elm
 #4   4   544 598   Rm
```

Or another `base R` approach is

```
data[order(factor(data$name, levels=names(sort(-table(data$name))))),]
#    chr start end name
# 1   1   234 267  ttn
# 3   3   445 489  ttn
# 5   5   644 680  ttn
# 2   2   345 367  Elm
# 4   4   544 598   Rm
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
 data %>% 
     group_by(name) %>% 
     mutate(n=n()) %>%
     arrange(-n) %>%
     select(-n)
```

Comment: First base example probably doesn't give what is wanted when there are multiples with the same count interleaved. It would sort by count but not group same names together.